# Migrating from log4j1 to log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I'm migrating from log4j1 to log4j2, but as many peoples said, te method getAllAppenders does not exist any more.

I have two pieces of code to be replaced but I did not find a pretty wa to do it :

```
    try {
        // termination
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Enumeration<Appender> appenders = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
        if(appenders != null) {
            while (appenders.hasMoreElements()) {
                Appender appender = appenders.nextElement();
                if (appender instanceof AsyncAppender) {
                    appender.close();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //forget exception
    }
```

The second one is :

```
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    FileAppender fileAppender = (FileAppender) ((AsyncAppender) rootLogger.getAppender("ASYNC")).getAppender("file");
    mailService.sendAlertForFXTraderSupport(env, user, new File(fileAppender.getFile()),executionFolder);
```

my log4j2 :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-d{yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="file"
        fileName="C:/temp/tetrafx-gui-dev-${tetrafx.location}.log"
        filePattern="C:/temp/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/tetrafx-gui-dev-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%-d{yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Async name="ASYNC" bufferSize="1000">
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout" />
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Have you any suggestion for that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first one, closing Appenders, is not something your application needs to do anymore in Log4j 2. Log4j 2 has a shutdown hook that takes care of all necessary cleanup.

For the second question, you can obtain the file appender and file name with:

```
LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
RollingFileAppender rfa = (RollingFileAppender) config.getAppender("file");
String fileName = rfa.getManager().getFileName();
```